# PyTorch, быстрый старт

Tags: нейронные-сети, pytorch

Подскажите пожалуйста ресурс для быстрого старта работы с PyTorch (без общей теории глубокого обучения) помимо документации. Может есть хороший курс, книга? Желательно на русском.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько ресурсов, которые могут помочь в быстром старте работы с PyTorch:

"Deep Learning и PyTorch. Быстрый старт" - книга автора Ильи Кашникова, которая дает основы использования PyTorch и применения в задачах компьютерного зрения и есть на русском языке.

"PyTorch для начинающих" - курс на сайте Skillbox, который дает основные знания о PyTorch и его использовании в задачах машинного обучения и на русском языке.

"PyTorch Zero to GANs" - курс на Coursera, который дает основы PyTorch и его применения в задачах глубокого обучения. Курс также предоставляет практические задания и примеры кода, которые помогут вам быстро освоить библиотеку PyTorch и его функционал. Курс доступен на английском языке.

Важно отметить, что старт с PyTorch не требует знания теории глубокого обучения, так как библиотека содержит множество готовых слоев и средств для решения задач машинного обучения.

Comment: и еще вот статья с книгами https://proglib.io/p/deep-learning-books

Comment: "Deep Learning и PyTorch. Быстрый старт" - как то не удается нагуглить что это за книга автора Ильи Кашникова.